# Weak Entity Mapping in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping

I have 2 classes:

```
@Entity
class A{
    @Id
    long id
    @???
    List<B> bs;
}

@????
class B{
    @ManyToOne
    A a;
    @OneToOne
    C c;
    Integer a,b,c,d,e;
}
```

how can i make hibernate to handle it ??
i dont want to put id on class  B as it's a weak entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by 'weak' entity? It just doesn't have an ID? Use

```
@ElementCollection
List<B> bs;
```

Along with

```
@Embeddable
class B {}
```

Find an example for instance [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection)

Comment: where can i find it?? org.hibernate.annotation or java.persistence?? none of them contains it.!:(